# Is it possible to set access to a folder such that ONLY the owner can access or take ownership?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, active-directory

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but I'm hoping to hear from others who have built a directory security app. I am trying to make an application that will allow me to create and take ownership of a folder, and NO OTHER USER will be able to take ownership of *that folder* (or at least something close). Is this possible? How can I go about this? [DACL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_discretionary_access_control_list_gly), [takeown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), [subinacl](http://ss64.com/nt/subinacl.html)?

**PS:** Someone suggested writing a service to lock the folder by some kind of filter or monitor but didn't give clear directions. Could that be the way  to go?

Comment: So.. you want the owner to be the only one that can take ownership?  Uhhh... have you actually thought about that?

Comment: @MystereMan: Yes, is this possible, I understand it may not be advisable but I want to know if it's possible. Encryption would have been the best but it takes a *really* **long time**.

Comment: Again.. have you actually THOUGHT about this?  How can someone take ownership of something they already own?  What's the point?  And more relevant, why are you trying to implement a function that effectively does nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing here is that anybody with "administrative privileges" can gain access to any resource hosted on the PC they are administering. There's the "take ownership" privilege for one which allows the user to take ownership of ANY resource (held by the admins only by default) and there's the "backup files and directories" privilege that allows to bypass NTFS security altogether which isn't enabled by default (it takes a tool to use that even as administrator).

So easy answer: without encryption: no.